# Custom ObjectMapper ignored after migration to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

Before migrating to `Spring Boot 2.1.0` I had the following `ObjectMapper` configured by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` working as expected.

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = buildObjectMapper();

private static ObjectMapper buildObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.configOverride(LocalDate.class).
            setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    return mapper;
}

public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return objectMapper;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper)); // JSON converter
}
}
```

However after migrating I can see that setting PropertyNamingStrategy seems to have no effect, my application still expects the format of `JSON` fields to match the default (e.g. requires "bloodType" instead of "blood-type" as expected).

I don't think that there is any problem with the mapper itself as I use the static `getObjectMapper` to share the same instance with `REST Assured` via `RestAssuredConfig` and seems to be still behaving as expected, if I update my custom mapper to the default behavior (commenting `setPropertyNamingStrategy`) everything seem to work as expected.

**EDIT 1**

In fact my whole mapper is being ignored, I tried to change the `LocalDate` format and it also made no difference. Updating the title to reflect the problem better.

Comment: I think your mapper propertyNamingStrategy is not get by spring boot application its getting from hibernate propertyNamingStrategy you should try this.

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.example.MyPhysicalNamingStrategy
Reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, which according to the documentation takes complete control of Spring MVC which is not what I wanted originally but at least makes sense. It's not clear for me why it was working before my migration to `Spring Boot 2` and why extending the the Spring MVC behavior doesn't work anymore.

I would be grateful for one answer that would add a good explanation for this, and ideally would avoid the full override by `@EnableWebMvc`.

**EDIT 1**

> Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring
>   Boot adds it automatically when it sees **spring-webmvc** on the
>   classpath.

Reference: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Unfortunately it's not a complete explanation for me as I can see `spring-webmvc:5.1.2.RELEASE` in my classpath.

**I will mark this as answered considering that using `@EnableWebMvc` or configuring one `@Bean` for `ObjectMapper` are working as expected.**

I will would still like to know why the `@EnableWebMvc` was needed, considering that according to the documentation it shouldn't.

Comment: Any luck with finding a solution avoiding the full override by @EnableWebMvc?

Comment: I couldn't find the reason for the need of `@EnableWebMvc` so I ended up removing `@EnableWebMvc` for the project I was working on and using an `ObjectMapper` bean. I don't have any plans to come back to this but I would like to understand why it didn't work in the first as my whole wrapper was being ignored, in any case you can check what I did in my project and see if it helps in any way: https://github.com/taizel/donor-calendar/tree/master/webapp/src/main/java/org/donorcalendar

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I was facing self-caused problems due to leftover `@JsonFormat` on a tested DTO. In the end I was able to achieve what I needed by just providing a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean.

Answer (score 2):

I think your mapper `propertyNamingStrategy` is not get by `spring boot application` its getting from hibernate `propertyNamingStrategy` you should try this.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.example.MyPhysicalNamingStrategy`

**Reference**: docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/…

OR:

```
   @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = jsonMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem can be seem on the JSON request parsed, at the REST controller the parsed object misses the fields that doesn't match the default format. Hibernate shouldn't be involved at this point, but maybe there is some Spring magic in place, in any case do you know how to set this property to have the KEBAB_CASE strategy so I could test your suggestion? For me this property should be used for something different, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: You can try my suggestion and provide your feed back. I think it will work .

Comment: I've tried your second suggestion, I replaced `configureMessageConverters` with your `extendMessageConverters` and still the same issue, however while doing that I decided to try to change my `LocalDate` format to see if it would have any difference and that this is also being ignored. I think it's a more general configuration issue as it seem that my custom `ObjectMapper` is completely ignored. I'm looking into the latest documentation to see what I'm doing wrong, I haven't found a big difference yet on the `Spring Boot 2` documentation so far for those points.